# Retrive the track image from android mediastore,.audio.media content provider?

Tags: android, audio, mediastore

It is possible to retrieve each track image from the mediastore audio content provider? I am not sure whether they have separate images for each audio track, or if they only have a single image for each album.  If possible, please provide a solution or corresponding link.

Answer (score 3):

Android does not save it as the "track image", but the "album image". So you have to do another query to the Album data:

albumId comes from the cursor that loads the songs:

```
long albumId = cursor.getLong(7);
Cursor artCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART},
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+" =?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(albumId)},
        null);
String albumArt;
if(artCursor.moveToNext()) {
    albumArt = "file://"+artCursor.getString(0);
} else {
    albumArt = null;
}
artCursor.close();

if(albumArt != null) {
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(albumArt));
}
```

Comment: what is the type of "albumArt" string or bitmap.i assume that is the path of album image.But how can i get the image from that path?

Comment: Yes, it's the path. To get the bitmap behind it, you would use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(albumArt));`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Android 10, due to increased security.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on Android 10, using kotlin and glide:

```
    val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),
        getItem(position)?.album_id?.toLong() ?: -1
    )

    Glide.with(holder.song_thumb.context)
        .load(uri)
        .into(holder.song_thumb)
```

getItem(position)?.album_id is the album id on the track retrieved using cursor on the content provider.

On Android 10, this Uri is accessible, while the path retrieved with the query on the content provider is not (regardless the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission).